# Updating AVL Tree Problem

Tags: java, recursion, avl-tree

As of now I only have been working on implementing the same side AVL Tree update.

The problem I am getting is my display function is blowing up after the Binary Search Tree goes through the AVL reorder. I move the pointers accordingly but when the function breaks, another object is inserted and I can not for the life of me debug it. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
AVLTree tree = new AVLTree(3)
tree.insert(2);
tree.insert(1); //causes the problem
tree.print();
```

here is my AVLTree class

```
public class AVLTree {

private boolean verboseMode = true;

private Comparable data;
private AVLTree left, right, parent;
private int rightHeight = -1, leftHeight = -1;

public AVLTree(Comparable obj){
    data = obj; left = null; right = null; parent = null;
}

private AVLTree(Comparable obj, AVLTree l, AVLTree r, AVLTree p){
    data = obj; left = l; right = r; parent = p;
}



public void insert(Comparable obj){
    int compare = obj.compareTo(data);
    if(compare != 0)
        if(compare < 0)
            if(left == null){
                left = new AVLTree(obj, null, null, this);
                // comment out for standard BST //
                left.updateHeight();            //
                left.updateBalance();           //
                // ///////////////////////////////
            } else
                left.insert(obj);
        else
            if(right == null){
                right = new AVLTree(obj, null, null, this);
                // comment out for standard BST //
                right.updateHeight();           //
                right.updateBalance();          //
                // ///////////////////////////////
            } else
                right.insert(obj);
    else
        System.err.printf("Object '%o' already in tree\n", obj);
}

public void updateHeight(){
    if(this.parent != null){
        if(this == this.parent.left)
            this.parent.leftHeight += 1;
        if(this == this.parent.right)
            this.parent.rightHeight += 1;
        this.parent.updateHeight();
    }
}

public void updateBalance(){
    if(this.parent != null){
        int diff = this.parent.leftHeight - this.parent.rightHeight;
        if(diff > 1 || diff < -1){
            if(this.parent.leftHeight > this.parent.rightHeight){
                AVLTree t0 = this.parent.parent;
                AVLTree t1 = this.parent;
                AVLTree t3 = this.parent.right;
                AVLTree t4 = this.right;
                this.right = t1;
                this.right.parent = this;
                if(t0 == null)
                    this.parent = null;
                else {
                    if(this == this.parent.left){
                        this.parent = t0;
                        this.parent.left = this;
                    } else {
                        this.parent = t0;
                        this.parent.right = this;
                    }
                }
                if(t4 == null)
                    this.right.left = null;
                else {
                    this.right.left = t4;
                    this.right.left.parent = this.right;
                }
                if(t3 == null)
                    this.right.right = null;
                else {
                    this.right.right = t3;
                    this.right.right.parent = this.right;
                }
            }               
        } else
            this.parent.updateBalance();
    }           
}       

public void print(){
    String loc = ""; print(loc);
} 
public void print(String loc){
    if(this.left != null){
        String tempLoc = loc+"0";
        left.print(tempLoc);
    }
    if(this.right != null){
        String tempLoc = loc+"1";
        right.print(tempLoc);
    }
    if(!verboseMode){
        System.out.printf("%s[%s], ", data, loc);
    } else
        System.out.printf("%s[%s] \t[%d, %d]\n\n", data, loc, leftHeight, rightHeight);         
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the following:
When you call the line
`tree.insert(1); //causes the problem`
you shuffle the tree and the top/root node get changed/rearranged;
But your `tree` variable points to the old root before the tree is rearranged. So your code is doing exactly what you told it to do.

You can this method to the class:

> public AVLTree getRoot() {
>
> ```
>     if(parent != null) {
>        return parent.getRoot();
>     } else {
>        return this;
>     }
> }
> ```

and also create the following main() function:

> ```
>   public static void main(String[] args) {     
>     AVLTree tree = new AVLTree(3);
>     System.out.println(tree.getRoot());
>     tree.insert(2);
>     System.out.println(tree.getRoot());
>     tree.insert(1); //causes the problem
>     System.out.println(tree.getRoot());
>     tree.getRoot().print();
>     tree.print();
>   }
> ```

The sample output from a run is as follows:

> ```
> AVLTree@47b480
> AVLTree@47b480
> AVLTree@9b49e6
> 1[0]  [-1, -1]
> 3[1]  [1, -1]
> 2[]   [0, -1]
> 3[]   [1, -1] //this comes from the second call to print
> ```